# Row reducing an integer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, gaussian-elimination, smith-normal-form

Given a $n\times n$ integer matrix, what is the best row reduction that can be found using only integer row operations of the form:

- an integer multiple of row $i$ can be added to row $j$
- row i can be multiplied by $\pm 1$
- row $i$ can be swapped with row $j$

It is possible to reduce the matrix into a triangular form. Does the triangular matrix preserve any information from the original matrix? Do the values of the triangular matrix contain any information about the original matrix?

Is there something analogous to the Smith normal form (but presumably less reduced somehow) that exists using only row operations?

Comment: The row reduced form of an integer entry augmented matrix can preserve information about solutions of a linear system in much the same way as Gaussian elimination.  Care is sometimes needed to avoid overflow in intermediate results using integer only arithmetic, and I can point you to past literature on that topic.

Comment: @hardmath that would be great! The matrix in question is actually a symplectic matrix consisting of rational numbers, but can be written as an integer matrix multiplied by some constant. I would like to know if the properties of the symplectic matrix are somehow retained after integer row reduction